# Automated TFS-based CI UI tests with desktop interaction

Tags: c#, tfs, windows-services, continuous-integration

I'm running some automated Continuous Integration tests through a TFS build. The tests are written using the Microsoft UI Automation Framework on MSTest, and are configured to run locally on the build agent, **without any controller or agent**.

Now, the tests themselves execute well. The Startup method of the test suite launches the compiled application's executable and the process shows up in the server's task manager. However, since this is done through the Team Foundation Build Service, the UI isn't actually shown, as services are not allowed to interact with the active desktop.

Is there a way to force the application's UI to appear on the active desktop? I'm aware that I can install a test controller and agent that allow tests interaction with the desktop, however this creates additional overhead and some technical problems, as we're using VS2012 against TFS2010, which goes directly to the VS2010 MSTest and thus to the VS2010 test controller & agent, which I cannot configure through VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting up a test controller a test agent. Apparently, with VS2010 it's not possible to install a test agent on the same server with the build controller, so I went for a separate machine altogether.

The tests run nicely now!

Answer (score 0):

With what account are you logged on to the build server?

Only if you are logged on with the build account you will see the interaction with the desktop/UI.

Comment: I'm not logged in with the build account, I don't actually have access to its credentials (the service was defined to run as that user when the build was set up).

Comment: Ok. Then you will not be able to see the interactions. How about setting up a dedicated (UI) test machine and define a test account. I know you don't want to install test controller & agent, but it's fairly easy. So why don't give it a try.